# Core Data - User Input selection multiple predicates - View results / Later save it to Favorite searches

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nspredicate

I am trying to build an app that let users to select from a series of values to compose the final filter criteria. And later save it to "User favorite searches".

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEvSz.png)

In my example the user should chose to filter Houses with 1 Room, 2 Bathrooms, Area 100 > 200mp, etc. and see all results with matching criteria.

In my app i use the standart FetchRequest entity. I would like to have something like this:

```swift
@FetchRequest(entity: Listing.entity(),sortDescriptors:[NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Listing.publishdate, ascending: false),],predicate: NSPredicate(format: "category == %@ AND rooms == %@" AND ==%@ bathrooms, "House", "User Input Nr of rooms", "User input nr of Bathrooms"))
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Use `NSCompoundPredicate`, make each of the "sub predicates" (one for category, one for rooms, etc.), and then combine them. Save each of the sub-predicates, that might be easier.

Comment: ok but filters should be combined dinamicaly when user pres the button. How do i link each button as a part of FetchRequest?